# How to upload a file into collab from local drive? i am completely new in coding

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to add file into google colab.

For that I have written the code to upload the file but after uploading file and running a program, still it is showing `key error: 'data.csv'`

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

import io
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['data.csv']))
```

I want upload and read the csv file in colab

Comment: What is the output of `print (uploaded.keys())`

Comment: That code works perfectly, you just must ensure that uploaded file's filename is data.csv.